# Defference Between #if #else #endif And Regular if, else

Tags: c#, .net

As the title states, I was wondering what are the differences between using

```
#if
   DoWork();
#else
   DoAnotherWork();
#endif
```

and

```
if (debug)
   DoWork();
else
   DoAnotherWork();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if (debug)
    DoWork();
else
    DoAnotherWork();
```

The above code will be compiled and the condition will be checked at runtime.

```
#if
    DoWork();
#else
    DoAnotherWork();
#endif
```

These statements will be checked at compile time.

So if #if condition is true, DoWork(); will be compiled and otherwise DoAnotherWork(); will be compiled. Where as in the previous example all code including the if statement will be compiled.

Please read this on Preprocessor Directives

[Preprocessor Directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx)

Comment: You may also add a link to the Logical Directives

Answer (score 9):

First is [Preprocessor Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and second [Logical statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/676s4xab%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Despite the volume of upvotes, this is not the best answer.  without the links, your answer does not explain the meaning of both concepts.  Your answer should stand alone for future reference.  Please consider expanding your answer so the links supplement the answer not provide the only details

Comment: I think it stands quite well alone. It is an explanation in a sentence and there is no need to click the links to understand it.

Answer (score 6):

The first version uses preprocessor directives. These are instructions for the compiler itself to only compile certain statements. The resulting executable file will only include the compiled statements. The condition must therefore be something that can be evaluated at compile time.

The second version is evaluated at run time. The compiler will compile all the statements as well as the logic to evaluate the `if` condition. All statements will be included in the resulting executable file. And which statement is actually executed will be determined when your code runs.